# How to design a model in Blazor with relation to authentication user using Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, authentication, blazor-server-side

I started to design an application in Blazor Server Side, that has the authentication for individual user accounts that comes with Blazor. So there are already those database tables like "AspNetUsers" with the UserName and so on.

Now I want to create a new table, that will be a simple entry the user can store in the database. Let's simplify the structure of the entry I have in mind, so that it has the following properties:

- EntryId (PK)
- UserId (FK)
- EntryText
- Date

I want to use the code first approach. I don't know, how the associated model for the entry entity has to look, so that entity framework recognizes the connection between the entry and the user.
In the Microsoft documentation for EFCore is an example for relationships, where is a Blog and a Post entity and in the Blog class is a List of Posts and the Post has a Blog property.
By creating the tables of the user by using the authentication of Blazor I do not have a model class of the User (or am I already wrong here?). Should I create a User model class, so that I can put a List of Entries inside the User and give the Entry a User property? And if I create that User class, how do I have to do that, so that entity framework knows that this class is associated with the user entity in the database?

Sorry, I'm new to Entity Framework and Authentication and designing database structures. I'm sure that the question isn't hard to answer, but I'm a bit confused by entity framework.

Greetings
Stefan

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I've figured out myself, how to do it. The database first approach simply works much better for me.
I created the Entry entity at the database, defined the UserId as Foreign Key. After running the command that lets entity framework build the model classes, the entry class had it User property and the hat its ICollection of Entrys.
Slowly I understand the magic that entity framwork does ;)